# Search multiple fields in table with mySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the fields:

```
id | name | surname | email | pin
```

I want to search every field above (apart from id) with a user entered keyword.

I'm not sure how to structure the sql though.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE ?????
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Not relevant to the question but if you are using a user supplied keyword, make sure you are using parameterized queries, otherwise you're opening yourself up to SQL Injection. See http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select *from users where name like %keyword% or surename like %keyword% or email like %keyword% or pin like %keyword%
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `WHERE` with `OR` between each field

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE name = yourValue
  OR surname = yourValue
  OR email = yourValue
  OR pin = yourValue
```